# Handle Null Values when using CustomSchema in apache spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am importing data based on a customSchema which I have defined in the following way

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField,DoubleType,StringType };
val customSchema_train = StructType(Array(
          StructField("x53",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("x95",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("x88",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("x30",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("x42",DoubleType,true),
          StructField("x28",DoubleType,true)
))

val train_orig = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").schema(customSchema_train).option("nullValue","null").load("/....../train.csv").cache
```

Now I know there are null values in my data which are there as "null" and I have tried to handle that accordingly. The import happens without any error but when I try to describe the data I get this error

```
train_df.describe().show
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 46.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 46.0 (TID 56, localhost): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "null"
```

How Can handle this error?

Comment: which version of spark-csv are you using? see https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/290